# setInterval changing local state

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I got a question I have an interval for my component:

```
  componentDidMount(){
this.timeID=setInterval(()=>{
  this.setState({
    text:this.props.text+"."
  })
  console.log(this.state.text);
},1000)
```

}
with this I would like to receive adding "." each second to text. But for now it adds only one dots. Can you please help me resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved problem- in setState I should change this.state.text not this.props.text. Maybe it would be helpful to someone in future